# How to check if a song exists?

Tags: c#, mysql

I can Insert, Update, Delete and Search the MySql Database

I wish to know how to check if a Song **Exists** in MySql DataBase ...

```
void CheckIfFileExists(String file, String dir)
{
    //   $mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DATABASE);
    string song = Path.GetFileName(file);
            song = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.DoubleQuoteString(song);
    string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = *; 
                         username = ***; password = *****";
     string sql = "SELECT id FROM music WHERE song = " + song);
 
   
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
             //if id exixts?
            if (???????????)
            {
               // "Song exists";
            }
            else
            {
              // "Song does not exist";
              InsertIntoDataBase(String file, String dir);
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't concatenate input to create SQL strings. What if the song is called `0; drop table music; --` ? Apart from that you already have a query that returns the ID of the song. You need to execute it and retrieve the result. That's done with `ExecuteReader` or when only one result is expected, `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php.  Or, simply count the number of records returned from your query and see if they are greater than zero.

Comment: See also [How to UPSERT in MySQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/).

Comment: BTW **no** amount of quoting and escaping can prevent SQL injection. It's actually a lot easier to write proper parameterized queries. If you use a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), all the code can be replaced with a single line: `var count=cn.ExecuteScalar("select count(*) from music where song=@song",new {song="whatever"});`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: `Count` is an overshoot: we want to know if at least one song with a given name, not the number of songs with potentially duplicate names

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that's not the point here. One could write an entire article on how to properly upsert. As Robert Harvey suggested, the *real* solution is executing an `INSERT IGNORE` - parameterized of course. The OP doesn't yet know how to execute the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go straight to the real issue, how to upsert correctly, before the question gets closed. Use MySQL's custom `INSERT IGNORE` and parameterized queries. Using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) makes this a one-liner:

```
var sql=@"INSERT IGNORE INTO music
    (ID,song,folder)
VALUES (1, @song,@folder)";

using (var cn= new MySqlConnection(ConString))
{
    cn.Execute(sql,new {song=song,folder=@dir});
}
```

Dapper will open the connection to execute the command and close it afterwards. It will generate a MySqlCommand, generate parameters for every property in the supplied object (@song for song, @folder for folder).

`INSERT IGNORE` will try to insert a new row to the table. If a row with the same primary key already exists, the INSERT will be ignored.

Generating SQL strings by concatenating input is *very* dangerous. No amount of quoting can prevent SQL injection attacks, or more benign conversion errors. What would happen if the song was named `'0'; DROP TABLE music;--` ? What if the value was a date or number? The query string would end up with invalid characters.

Parameterized queries on the other hand are like C# functions. The parameters are passed to the server outside the string itself, as part of the RPC call. The server generates an execution plan from the query and feeds the parameter values to the compiled execution plan.

The values never change to text or get combined with the query, so there's no way to inject SQL or end up with type conversion issues